# Crash occurs when trying to add UInavigationBar button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a right navigation bar button item into a view programmatically and the code that I use is as follows:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: Selector(("buttonTapped:")))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

The function that responds to tap on the added right bar button is as follows:

```
func buttonTapped() {
    print("Right Bar button action")
}
```

When I am trying to run the project, the newly added right bar button is appearing on the navigation bar. But when I tap on it, the following error comes up and the app crashes.

```
2017-08-08 12:37:26.641 Grow[14229:3786869] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Grow.DashBoardViewControllerMain rightButtonAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd719c12700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101c2b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011317c141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110232134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110149840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101493b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001113e4d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000011181f917 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 149
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001113e4d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001115695ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001115698c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000111569a3b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 822
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000111568802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001114527ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000111453f00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000111400a84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000111be45d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000111bdc532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110168c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011014e0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011014d5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011014d016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011646ca24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001113e3134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  Grow                                0x000000010f32f5a7 main + 55
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114e3665d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: #selector("buttonTapped:")

Comment: Colons ":" used when there is extra param in function. But there is none in your function.

Comment: let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
action: Selector(("buttonTapped:"))
```

If is referencing a selector called `buttonTapped:`.

Your function, however, is named `buttonTapped`, without a parameter. Modify your selector accordingly, so it will take a `UIBarButtonItem` parameter.

On another note, you should use `#selector(functionName)`, as it has real-time name checking and could warn you about a missing function.

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:))))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button

func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Right bar button action")
}
```

Comment: I have modified the question since there were some typing mistakes... Please have a look at it again..

Comment: @JobinsJohn I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In code

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: Selector(("buttonTapped")))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button

func buttonTapped() {
    print("Right Bar button action")
}
```

The crash reports that action `rightButtonAction`: was not found.
Please recheck and replace `rightButtonAction`: with `buttonTapped` where `buttonTapped` is a method on `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector requires a function which have an argument. While your function doesn't have that.

Write  function like below considering you are using **Swift 2**.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
 print("Right Bar button action")
}
```

If using **swift 3** then write **selector** like below

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(Your_View_Controller.buttonTapped(_ :)))
```

and **write function** like

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
 print("Right Bar button action")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button:)))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button

func buttonTapped(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("bar button taped")
}
```

Comment: Please add a description which triggers the error and what solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `buttonTapped` function is not taking any parameters. So you do not need to use `:` (colon)

Try removing it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
```

instead of these two lines:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self, action: Selector(("buttonTapped:")))    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

Answer (score 0):

Error occur because you set ':' in selector text. It's means you wait parameter in you function(sender), but you function has no parameters. (and in runtime system can't find function) You can try delete ':' symbol or add sender parameter in your function. I'd like write something like this

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add,     target: self, action:  #selector(buttonTapped))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

The function:

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Right Bar button action")
}
```